# How to read values from a NO2 sensor from an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sensor, adc

Alphasense sells this NO2 sensor:

http://www.alphasense.com/environmental-sensors/alphasense_downloads.html

http://www.alphasense.com/environmental-sensors/pdf/NO2B4.pdf

How can I read the values from an Arduino ? Do I need something between the Arduino and the sensor ?

I have used a few basic sensors before, but I'm confused with this gas sensor: why  does the response curve seem to loop ? I naively expected a constant tension for a given concentration, but it looks like it is more complicated with chemical sensors.

Comment: You need to decide what you are asking about.  Is this about what analogRead() does and how to use it, or about how to connect the sensor electrically to a microcontroller?

Comment: @Olin -- I think he is asking about the analog front-end, at least, that's how I read it.

Comment: @DrFri: The point is we shouldn't have to guess.

Comment: @Olin -- Completely agree with you... BTW, I've come across a few of your previous answers, you've done some really nice work on this site. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

What range of concentrations of NO<sub>2</sub> will you be measuring?
Which Arduino model are you using?

The sensor outputs current proportional to the concentration of NO<sub>2</sub>.  Have a look at fig.4 in the [datasheet](http://www.alphasense.com/environmental-sensors/pdf/NO2B4.pdf).  It shows the voltages for different concentrations of NO<sub>2</sub>, if you run connect a 33Ω load resistor from the sensor output to GND.

[image]

Notice the offset: 0ppb corresponds to 170mV.  The 0ppb to 200ppb operating range corresponds to 45mV output range.  If you use a load resistor with a larger value, you will get get a larger output range.  Unfortunately, the datasheet doesn't say what's the maximum load resistance can be.

Now we get into the Arduino side of things.  If you use `analogRead()` with the default [voltage reference setting](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference), 45mV would corresponds to 9 A/D counts.  This is worst/simplest case.

If you're willing to add more hardware, you can amplify the output voltage with a non-inverting OpAmp.  With 33Ω load resistor and a gain of 20, your output range would be or 900mV or 183 A/D counts.

Comment: Before going any further I don't really understand this graph; why is time involved in the reading of a concentration ? Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: About the additional hardware: on another project using the same sensor, the person who designed the project used a sigma delta ADC to read the sensor on a Raspberry Pi. How does that compare to your solution with an OpAmp ?

Comment: @Antoine  I think, the designers of the sensor were demonstrating the step response in fig.4.  The time axis is not really important for your question.